# Problem with reading/writing on the terminal line

Tags: c, string, buffer, getchar

I am trying to write a function that reads an input from the terminal using getchar() and stores it in a string and then display it in 2 different formats.

- The read line should be stored in the string followed by the null-character ('\o').
- The newline character shouldn't be stored in the string.

The problem I'm encountering is the fact that when the user inputs less characters than the assigned length, the enter key must be pressed twice, and then a newline character also gets stored in the string.
No solutions regarding the buffer, which I suppose to be the culprit, found in other locations were of any help.
Any suggestion and explanation is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

This is my last version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LENGTH 4//30// i will try a shorter lenth for troubleshooting

void flushBuffer(void){
    while((getchar()) != '\n' );// consume the rest of a partially-read line
}
void readLine(char str[], int length){
    for(int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++){ 
        if(str[j] == '\n'){
            str[j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    do {
        str[i] = getchar();
        i++;
    } while (i < length - 1  && str[i - 1] != '\n');
    str[i] = '\0';
}
void printArray(char a[], int length){
  printf("[");
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(a[i] == '\n'){
      printf("\\n");
    }else if(a[i] == '\0'){
      printf("\\0");
    }else{
      printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
    if(i != length - 1){
      printf(",");
    }
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
void printChar (char c) {
  putchar(c);
  fflush(NULL);
}
void printString (char s[]) {
  int currentChar = 0;
  printf("\"");
  do{
  printChar(s[currentChar]);
  currentChar++;
  }while (s[currentChar] != '\0');
  printf("\"\n");
}
int main (void) {
  char inputString[LENGTH];
  do{
    printf("String? ");
    readLine(inputString, LENGTH);
    flushBuffer();
    printArray(inputString, LENGTH);
    printString(inputString);
    flushBuffer();
  }while(1);
}
```

I tried writing a funtion that should flush my buffer ( flushBuffer() ) and in the function that has the task of reading the input line (readLine()) I tried getting rid of any stored '\n'.

Comment: Do try and use *longer* buffers for debugging, not shorter. Also, consider `while (1) { ... }` or `for (;;) { ... }` versus the highly unusual `do { ... } while (1)`.

Comment: Careful with `readLine` operating on an uninitialized buffer.

Comment: _the enter key must be pressed twice_ You call `flushBuffer();` twice in the `main` loop.

Comment: I changed the `do while` to a `while` and that didn't resolve my issue. What do you mean uninitialized buffer? @tadman

Comment: I deleted the first call of the `flushBuffer();`, the need for a double enter-key press still exists. @001

Comment: Any reason you're not using the built-in `fgets()`?

Comment: What's the reason for loop that replaces `\n` with `\0` in `readLine()`? You're going to overwrite the buffer with the user input immediately after.

Comment: If the original input is less than `LENGTH` characters, you read the newline in `readLine()`. So when you call `flushBuffer()` after printing the output, it waits for a second newline before printing the prompt.

Comment: Move the call to `flushBuffer()` into `readLine()`. Only do it if you didn't end the loop by reading a newline.

Comment: I have to use `getchar()` as it is a prerequisite for my assignment. Other than that, I implemented all the additional suggestions mentioned by you, however, the code is still not running as intended. @Barmar

Comment: You don't need `flushBuffer()`. Just have `readline()` _always_ read up to the `\n` or `EOF`. Just conditionally put the read chars in the array as long as they fit.

Comment: Uninitialized variables are the source of much frustration in the C world. When you declare a buffer like `char x[y]` it has no particular value set at the start. You should set it to *something* at first, like `""`, to settle it into a known state.

Comment: With a slightly different loop in the `readLine()` function I got the code to work using @Barmar 's advice.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support!

Answer (score 0):

This is the version of my code that is working properly. As suggested by @Barmar, the flushBuffer(), function that consumes all the characters including the newline that didn't have room in the string, was called online in the case when the '\n' wasn't detected by the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LENGTH 30

void flushBuffer(void){
    while((getchar()) != '\n' );//^part of Question: consume the rest of a partially-read line
}
void readLine(char str[], int length){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length - 1){
        str[i] = getchar();
        if (str[i] == '\n'){
          str[i] = '\0';
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    flushBuffer();
}
void printArray(char a[], int length){
  printf("[");
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(a[i] == '\n'){
      printf("\\n");
    }else if(a[i] == '\0'){
      printf("\\0");
    }else{
      printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
    if(i != length - 1){
      printf(",");
    }
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
void printChar (char c) {
  putchar(c);
  fflush(NULL);
}
void printString (char s[]) {
  int currentChar = 0;
  printf("\"");
  while (s[currentChar] != '\0'){
  printChar(s[currentChar]);
  currentChar++;
  }
  printf("\"\n");
}
int main (void) {
  char inputString[LENGTH] = "";
  do{
    printf("String? ");
    readLine(inputString, LENGTH);
    printArray(inputString, LENGTH);
    printString(inputString);
  }while(1);
}
```

Comment: `while((getchar()) != '\n' );` is an infinite loop when end-of-file occurs.

Comment: `fflush(NULL);` is a lot of flushing.  If you really think any flushing is needed, consider `fflush(stdout);` after printing a line.